# Unity build not having audio, Using an audiomanager

Tags: unity-game-engine

So im at a loss here ive been making this game and everything works perfectly in the unity player but when i build it anything using this audiomanager isnt giving out any sound. Im a beginner through and through so sorry if im dumb.

```
using UnityEngine.Audio;
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class AudioManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public static AudioManager instance;

    public AudioMixerGroup mixerGroup;

    public Sound[] sounds;

    void Awake()
    {
        if (instance != null)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            instance = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        }

        foreach (Sound s in sounds)
        {
            s.source = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
            s.source.clip = s.clip;
            s.source.loop = s.loop;

            s.source.outputAudioMixerGroup = mixerGroup;
        }
    }

    public void Play(string sound)
    {
        Sound s = Array.Find(sounds, item => item.name == sound);
        if (s == null)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Sound: " + name + " not found!");
            return;
        }

        s.source.volume = s.volume * (1f + UnityEngine.Random.Range(-s.volumeVariance / 2f, s.volumeVariance / 2f));
        s.source.pitch = s.pitch * (1f + UnityEngine.Random.Range(-s.pitchVariance / 2f, s.pitchVariance / 2f));

        s.source.Play();
    }

}
```

So this is the audiomanager script

And Im using `FindObjectOfType<AudioManager>().Play("AudioName");` to call it

Forgot to add this originally

```
using UnityEngine.Audio;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class Sound {

    public string name;

    public AudioClip clip;

    [Range(0f, 1f)]
    public float volume = .75f;
    [Range(0f, 1f)]
    public float volumeVariance = .1f;

    [Range(.1f, 3f)]
    public float pitch = 1f;
    [Range(0f, 1f)]
    public float pitchVariance = .1f;

    public bool loop = false;

    public AudioMixerGroup mixerGroup;

    [HideInInspector]
    public AudioSource source;

}
```

Comment: There is a library named UnityEngine.Audio? 
Haven't seen it before.
So what is thid Sound[] array?

Comment: I added the Sound script too its at the bottom of the post sorry about that.

Comment: And the UnityEngine.Audio library ?

Comment: What you're doing is adding component to your object to which AudioManager is attached to again and again in each iteration of the loop. In this line

s.source = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();

Do you mean to do this?

Comment: I think you also mean to use the sounds mixerGroup.  `s.source.outputAudioMixerGroup = s.mixerGroup;`  Its possible the AudioManagers mixerGroup is unset.

Comment: @HasnainShaukat the UnityEngine.Audio just has a few premade classes like audiosource audiomixer etc, I didnt make it all by myself i followed a tutorial and made adjustements as i needed but to my understanding yes its supposed to add an audiosource to the object from which it was called.

Comment: As for @hijinxbassist honestly might be it ill have to figure it out.

Comment: @hijinxbassist i now have configured a MixerGroup but it still doesnt play anything in the build.

Comment: What platform are you targeting in your build?  Does the target device have the volume muted or turned down?  Best place to start is putting debug logs all through the audio manager and checking the logs from the target device.

Comment: @hijinxbassist I figured it out the problem or well really just the mistake was in the Awake method so in the full build which included the main menu, the audiomanager in the main menu is different from the audiomanager from the game scene so in the build the main menu audiomanager was used which didnt have all the different sounds set up and it destroyed the one in the game scene so there werent any duplicates. Dumb mistake but oh well got it figured out atleast just made it a prefab and alls good.